# Is there a way to tell what type a pointer is actually pointing to in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, generic-programming

In C++ you can declare a pointer as one type, and then point it towards a different, inheriting type instead. Is there any way to tell which you're currently pointing at?

```
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo* foo = &bar;
    bool I_WANT_THIS_TO_BE_TRUE = (typeid(*foo) == typeid(Bar));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This fails because you did not declare any virtual functions in `Foo`. Alter that to have, for example, a virtual destructor, and you will get the hoped-for result.

Comment: Indeed, class is required to have virtual methods to be considered polymorphic (which is required for RTTI to make sense). But a class designed for polymorphism should always provide virtual destructor, so this is not a limitation.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is reflection, or RTTI (Run Time Type Information) stuff.

See this for info to get started on subject: [Attribute & Reflection libraries for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87932/attribute-reflection-libraries-for-c)

Unsurprisingly, wikipedia also has article about RTTI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Then there are frameworks which provide reflection features for objects derived from some common base class (which provides the reflection methods, inherited to all subclasses). An example is [Qt's meta object system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html). These can provide much more information than plain C++ RTTI, and provide full reflection support (such as calling a method by name not known at compile time, for example javascript code calling C++ method).