# C++ - Programmatically call correct function parameters

Tags: c++

I have a question. Say I have this code:

```
int myfunc(int arg-a, int arg-b); 
int mywrapperfunc(obj a, obj b);
```

mywrapperfunc is supposed to wrap myfunc. mywrapperfunc discards the first argument and takes the second, which is an array. I then uses the array items as parameters. But say I don't know how many parameters myfunc takes, nor do I know how many items are in the array-type object(b). How would I programmatically call myfunc with the correct number of args? The number of args handed over would be the same as the number of items in the array-type object.
EDIT: arg-a and arg-b are supposed to come from the array-type object. I split the object into the args.
EDIT: I'm trying to wrap Cython with some sense involved, hiding most background jobs.

Comment: I didn't understand any of this.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to do? To start, `arg-a` and `arg-b` are not valid identifiers.

Comment: Why not use an `std::vector` or `std::array` (if available)? Both of them know their size

Comment: What is the purpose of discarding the first argument? Why is it a parameter then?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to build your own language. Typically, then, you have to pass arguments as "argc, argv[]".

Comment: @JBently: It's a long story. For starts, another app calls a library which calls the semingly useless first arg.

Comment: For `mywrapperfunc` to call `myfunc`, it must either know about `myfunc` statically or have a pointer to it. Either way, it statically knows the type and therefore the number of argument. If that _isn't_ what is happening, please show how this is set up & invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `reflection`, you cannot do this with c++. Use another languages like java or c# for that.

Comment: Is there some Java wrapper I can use then? This is a wrapper that, do to some special reasons, must be written in C++. Is there some way I could do that part in another language and link it with the C++ object file?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos How about addressing the points raised as comments on the question (in particular, giving a clear code example), then hopefully someone can help you further.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: How about boost::reflection?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos, first you should clearly explain why do you need that. Maybe you can avoid it? It is great idea to avoid reflection everytime it is possible.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos, I don't know about `boost::reflection`, but you should watch a picture in [that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87932/attribute-reflection-libraries-for-c) to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: I am trying to make a wrapper for Cython. The person hands a copy of the function, the wrapper splits self and args as needed and gives the function the correct args. It will raise an error if Python gives too much/little args or improper data type. The goal is to make Cython's workings less obvious to the user.